# Obtener imagen de una Url externa con Html2canvas

Tags: javascript, url, canvas, screenshot

Estimados:

No domino mucho `canvas`, pero he intentado realizar un screnshoot de una página web a traves de la `URL`. ¿Es esto posible con `html2canvas`? ya que lo he realizado con otras funciones, pero no me permiten capturar toda la pagina web, ni tampoco modificar la calidad de la imagen.

```
function canvas () {

    var url = "http://www.portalinmobiliario.com";
    //var canvas = document.getElementById('div');
    var canvas = url;
    alert(canvas);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    alert(dataURL);
    var lowQuality = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.1);
    $('#preview').html('<img src="' + dataURL + '" alt="' + url + '">').show();

}
```

Comment: Podrías agregar el código que haz hecho en la pregunta. Gracias

Comment: no tengo mucho codigo... pero existe alguna funcion para poder capturar la Url y pasarla a base64???

Comment: agrega lo que haz hecho, así se te puede ayudar

Comment: function canvas() {

        var url = "http://www.portalinmobiliario.com/arriendo/departamento/barrio-republica-santiago-santiago-metropolitana?tp=2&op=2&ca=3&ts=1&dd=1&dh=6&bd=1&bh=6&or=&mn=1&sf=1&sp=0&pd=170.000&ph=250.000&pi=4fxyrn04t1ew4ctqdawonp2b";
        //var canvas = document.getElementById('div');
        var canvas = url;
        alert(canvas);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        alert(dataURL);
        var lowQuality = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.1);
        $('#preview').html('<img src="' + dataURL + '" alt="' + url + '">').show();
    }

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

[html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) es uno de los mejores proyectos para representar (de manera no perfecta) elementos `HTML` en un elemento `canvas`. Pero para usar los métodos `toDataURL` y `getImageData` las imágenes contenidas en el canvas tienes que proceder del mismo dominio, de lo contrario te lanzará un mensaje de seguridad. Al introducir imágenes de otro dominio obtendrás un [tainted canvas](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/182/the-canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data-and-tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported) que no te dejará llamar a los anteriores métodos en él.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo usar `html2canvas`:

**Código HTML**

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>Uno</li>
    <li>Dos</li>
    <li>Tres</li>
</ul>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**Código JavaScript**

```
var ul = document.getElementById("list");
var container = document.getElementById("container");

html2canvas(ul, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        container.appendChild(canvas);
    }
});
```

Y aquí [un jsfiddle funcionando](https://jsfiddle.net/yhsdz0dp/) para que puedas probar el código.

Pero para lo que deseas, si el `HTML` que intentas representar no se encuentra en tu mismo dominio, lo mejor es que uses herramientas como [PagePeeker](https://pagepeeker.com/) o [ShrinkTheWeb](https://www.shrinktheweb.com/).

> Nota: En tu ejemplo estás intentando llamar el método `toDataURL` en la variable `canvas`que es de tipo `String` (la variable que hace referencia al elemento `canvas` está comentada)